# nginx drop 403 error on http://localhost/

Tags: nginx

Have fresh installed nginx. It drops me 403 error on localhost. Tried to make any virtual hosts, but appears the same problem. Have the same error. Tried few days with different configs - no way. As I verified - I have right permissions on /var/www 
 There is my nginx.conf

```
user root;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

server {
   listen         80;
   listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; 
   server_name  localhost;
   root   /var/www;
   index  index.html index.htm index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_buffers 256 128k;
       fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
       fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
}
```

What I shall to do?

Comment: What does your nginx error logs say?

Comment: @NooBskie, now only this `2015/09/14 10:51:07 [error] 5002#0: *13 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbi$`

Comment: Try `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` Assuming `www-data` is your web service group

Comment: @NooBskie, what if I don't have such group and user?